# Jenkins MSdeploy Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_IISAPP

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, msdeploy

I am trying to deploy a .net application to a remote IIS server using Jenkins. I am building using the MSBuild plugin provided by Jenkins. When using Visual Studio and publishing the app, the application is getting deployed in the remote IIS server but when running through Jenkins using msdeploy. I get the following error:

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_IISAPP
More Information: Could not complete an operation with the specified provider ("iisApp") when connecting using the Web Management Service. This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized the user for this operation. iisApp http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_IISAPP.
Error count: 1.
```

I have tried all the answers in the StackOverflow and other website but nothing seems to be working. I tried giving permissions to the user in the remote IIS server but still, it is not working

**My MSDeploy command is:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test>"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
-verb=sync -source:iisApp="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test\src\PrecompiledWeb\localhost_31011" -dest:auto,
computerName=https://35.190.40.12:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=test,userName=admin,password=admin,authType=basic -allowUntrusted=true
```

Please, someone, help me. I am scratching my for days.

Comment: Hi pavan, did you build your .net application in VS or MSbuild with any errors? If it builds in VS with any errors, please share the detailed error log.

Comment: There are no errors displaying in building either in Jenkins or in visual studio. It is just showing build successfully with some warnings.